# How to implement pause and then resume in the text to speech using JAVA in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, text-to-speech

I am Creating an app for my school project, where it will read the whole text and speak i.e, TTS. Now I want to implement that, when the user press pause then TTS will stop and When user press Play then TTS will start to speak from the line where it was paused. I heard that it can be achieved by using Media player class but how to do that I don't know and how to put the code in the following code

Here is my TTS code that read the text that is input by the user.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button button;
EditText editText;
SeekBar seekBar;
TextToSpeech textToSpeech;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    editText = findViewById(R.id.edittext);
    seekBar = findViewById(R.id.seekbar);

    textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int i) {
            if (i == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS){
                int lang  = textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.US);

                if (lang == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || lang == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Language is not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Language Supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    });

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String data = editText.getText().toString();

            float speed = (float) seekBar.getProgress() / 50 ;
            if (speed < 0.1) speed = 0.1f;
            textToSpeech.setSpeechRate(speed);
            textToSpeech.speak(data,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (textToSpeech != null){
        textToSpeech.stop();
        textToSpeech.shutdown();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I ensure you that you can't pause/resume TTS nor use `MediaPlayer`. but you can divide your text to sentences and pass next line when previous is spoke out (there is an utternace listener). in such case `textToSpeech.stop()` will stop this one utterance and you will know its `id`, so you can "resume" playing from same id/sentence instead of beginning (first sentence)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I am new to this android, can you post some code how to do that please.

Comment: sadly, I can't, if I could I would post an answer ;) I've made TTS module (working in `Service`) in some app few years ago, which was reading whole articles, so I do remember some circulumstances, but I don't have access to code anymore

Comment: Okay no problem, Thank you